# How can I cache all mysql queries and results in my webpage instead of caching each query?

Tags: mysql

I did following changes for caching mysql queries in server

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 8388608;
SET GLOBAL query_cache_limit = 1048576;
SET GLOBAL query_cache_type = 1;
```

and I am getting following result in mysql

```
mysql> show variables like 'query%';
+------------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name                | Value   |
+------------------------------+---------+
| query_alloc_block_size       | 8192    |
| query_cache_limit            | 1048576 |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096    |
| query_cache_size             | 8388608 |
| query_cache_type             | ON      |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF     |
| query_prealloc_size          | 8192    |
+------------------------------+---------+
```

Is there anything I need to change in my php code to achieve caching for all the mysql queries ? Please check [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/speed-up-your-web-site-with-mysql-query-caching/)

Comment: You mean execute command like `SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 8388608;` on PHP or actually implement a database caching mechanism on PHP?

Comment: @apokryfos No. I am asking I have to do something in my code to complete the caching  or is it enough ? Please check this http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/speed-up-your-web-site-with-mysql-query-caching/

Comment: if I recall correctly, enabling query caching on MySQL is completely transparent and there shouldn't be the need to do anything on any other application.

Comment: You need to check your vars and see which ones you want to change. Determine which changes require conf file settings and/or a reboot.